# Connect to Organization.svc using STS token

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying for 2 days now to get STS token from ADFS. I made ASP.Net app that need to be certificated as user on hosted CRM. What is the easiest way to get currently logged in user on ADFS (from this machine) and use his credentials to login to CRM 2011 as he. I can't use network credentials cause I'm logging on hosting server over STS.

I tried to run `sdk\samplecode\cs\generalprogramming\authentication\ifdsinglesignon\` example using  [this link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509057.aspx) but still can't get certificated. I must say I not need to use user, domain and pass, cause I can't get them. **Must use token**.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, we can add sts reference using visual studio 2010:

1. Open Visual Studio, and right click the project to add STS reference.
2. Browse your application configuration location (web.config).
3. For the application URI use your custom asp.net website address. (example: https://customweb.mscrm.com)
4. Then click next go to Security Token Service page and choose Use an existing STS option. For the STS WS-Federation metadata document location use: https:///FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml
5. After this step, select the options that suits you.

You would have FederationMetadata and Web.config that being modified to point to STS.
Hopefully this answers

Cheers

Comment: Tnx for trying to help. I did this in sdk example, and all time i got windows login, instead of IFD. Do I need to change any setting in this wizard or in ADFS itself? I can't be logged in. After insert user and pass I get error all time from sts :-(

Comment: Hmm, maybe CRM/ADFS was not configured properly. Can you open CRM on your browser? And how the CRM authenticate? Does it redirect you to sts/popping up windows auth?

Comment: CRM works nice. It redirects you to STS web form login page. After you enter user and pass it redirects u to CRM start page. When I do this in my customer app, it redirects me to STS and after enter user and pass it returns me error page.